# Magento2 Cron job not running

Tags: cron, magento-2.1.8

I have made all the admin settings based on previous post from magento stack exchange. I have created a custom module to send emails and I want to schedule the email based on cron job. I want to know what is missing. If I run manually the cron job runs successfully and email is sent out. How do I make cron job run in the background so email gets sent out in a scheduled time everyday.

My Admin config settings:

[image: Cron configuration options for group: default]

[image: Cron configuration options for group: index]

My custom code `crontab.xml` is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="Daily_report" instance="Module\Modulename\Cron\sendEmail" method="execute">
            <schedule>*/1 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Here is the crontab set-up:

```
*/1 * * * * www-data php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
*/1 * * * * www-data php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
*/1 * * * * www-data php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

**UPDATE:**

I've updated crontab -e as below:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

I can see in /var/log/syslog that the cron is running. Below are the details:

```
Nov 25 12:52:01  CRON[30803]: (ubuntu) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log)
Nov 25 12:52:01  CRON[30800]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Nov 25 12:52:01 CRON[30804]: (ubuntu) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log)
Nov 25 12:52:01 CRON[30805]: (ubuntu) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/mage$
Nov 25 12:52:01  CRON[30801]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Nov 25 12:52:02  CRON[30802]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

However, none of the cron jobs ran. There is nothing in magento log files.

Could you please help me out? I have hosted my test server in AWS Ubuntu server.

Comment: I've given path wrong in the crontab which caused the issue. Now it is fixed. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first find php path using  below command

```
which php
```

whatever results come you need replace with php into cron setup

Also 
add below cron using ubuntu user :
crontab -e add below crontab

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Remove crontab from root user.

Comment: None of the existing jobs are working. I edited my question with Crontab set-up.

Answer (score 2):

If you run Magento in a cluster with several instances, you have to make sure to pick a master server that runs cron jobs.

Nethertheless, you can check if the cron was installed correctly with `crontab -l` .

If the cron does not show up, run `bin/magento cron:install` in your Magento dir. This command is available with Magento 2.2

Comment: This answer help me make cronjob run on my localhost with MAMP

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about AWS servers nevertheless everything makes me think that you did not configure any cronjob in you server's crontab.

With regards of AWS, here is an possible explanation of how to set cronjob in general: https://www.cumulations.com/blogs/37/How-to-write-Cron-jobs-on-Amazon-Web-ServicesAWS-EC2-server

And here is how to set a cronjob for Magento: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

So far you just configured Magento's inner so-called cronjob. It is not a real cronjob but a managed queue periodically run by the cronjob. So, in short, you should ssh to your server and execute:

> crontab -e

And then:

```
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> <magento install dir>/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento install dir>/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> <magento install dir>/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Cron will then execute magento's scripts which are actually responsible for managing queue and tasks.

Comment: I edited crontab and updated my question with the details.

Comment: Why did you put www-data in front of php? Remove it. And could you provide us with crontab logs? as default logs are in /var/log/syslog this will help us out however i think that removing www-data will be sufficent

Answer (score 0):

for a time period of less than 15 minutes, use the group id **index**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="index">
    <job name="Daily_report" instance="Module\Modulename\Cron\sendEmail" method="execute">
        <schedule>*/1 * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```